# Unable to redirect it with PHP_SELF in action

Tags: php, session, redirect

I am trying to redirect my page if the logins are true and also new with sessions too so it should work like if the details are not entered it should show an error message. Please help me with this code.

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['validate'])){
if(isset($_POST['Username'])){
$username=$_POST['Username'];
$password=$_POST['Passwd'];
if($username=='admin' && $password=='admin'){
$_SESSION['validate']=true;
echo "logged in..";
header('location:127.0.0.1/php/admin.php');
exit(0);
}
else{
    echo "Wrong Password";
}
}
else{
    echo "Set fields please..";
}
}

?>
<html>
<head><title>Login</title></head>
<body>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="POST">
<?php session_start(); ?>
<table border="0" align="center">
<tr>
    <td>Username:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Username"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Password:</td>
    <td><input type="Password" name="passwd"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><center><input type="submit" name="submit"></center></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot print anything before redirection.

Comment: You cannot change the headers, after output. if you remove "echo "logged in..";" on line 8, it should work juist fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['validate'])){
           echo "you are already logged in!";
         }
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
           $username=$_POST['Username'];
           $password=$_POST['Password'];
           if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)){
             if($username=='admin' && $password=='admin'){
                $_SESSION['validate']=true;
                //echo "logged in..";  //not required because after redirecting it will                                   stateless.
                header('location:127.0.0.1/php/admin.php');
                exit(0);
             }
             else{
                echo "Wrong Credential";
             }
           }
           else{
             echo "Set fields please..";//it will appear if credentials are empty..
            }
      }
      ?>
    <html>
    <head>
         <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
       <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="POST">
     <?php session_start(); ?>
     <table border="0" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td>Username:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="Username"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Password:</td>
           <td><input type="Password" name="password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><center><input type="submit" name="submit"></center></td>
        </tr>
       </table>
      </form>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Done! Its working great though there was a small mistake but I corrected it! :) Thankx alot jan_sat!

Comment: you are welcome..and thank you for choosing my answer as best.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['Username'])){
    $username=$_POST['Username'];
    $password=$_POST['passwd'];
    if($username == "admin" && $password=="admin"){
        $_SESSION['validate'] = true;
        echo "logged in..";
        header('location: http://127.0.0.1/php/admin.php');
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        echo "Wrong Password";
    }
}
else{
    echo "Set fields please..";
}


?>
<html>
<head><title>Login</title></head>
<body>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="POST">

<table border="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td>Username:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Username"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<td><input type="Password" name="passwd"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><center><input type="submit" name="submit"></center></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

removed if(isset($_SESSION['validate']))
cause the variable was not defined in your code
This works for me

Comment: It says "Set fields please.." on the page but I want it after I click on submit without giving any input and not directly..

Comment: It must say "Set fields please.." if no input is given! :(
I am really confused!